# Using Click to Deploy and install Jenkins in GCE

Tags: jenkins, google-compute-engine, bitnami

1. Using '**Click to Deploy**', I already deployed **LAMP stack**.
2. Now i want to use '**Click to deploy**'and then deploy **Jenkins** in the same **GCE instance**(dont want another fresh GCE instance)
3. Is there an option to use 'Click to deploy' for multiple tools or only once per GCE instance?
4. What is the best approach to install multiple tools using **Click to deploy** or **Google Launcher** under single **Google Compute Engine instance**?

   Plz someone help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami developer here.

Right now you can't use "click to deploy" twice in the same GCE instance.

You could access your instance via ssh, download bitnami jenkins stack and install it. Take into account that you'll be installing another apache server so you won't be able to use port 80 again (as well as with mysql).